# Failure to compile for arm64 devices

Tags: c++, linux, flutter, cmake, arm64

Hello i am quite new to linux and i am trying to do some cross-compilation to run a flutter app on an external device.

Setup :

- VM under virtual box : Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- External device : (imx8) with arm64

So i need to compile my app to match the `arm64` architecture but i am having many errors that i have no idea how to fix and no idea where they come from :

```
Failed to cmake:
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 14.0.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++ - broken
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/tom/test_app/build/elinux/arm64/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/tom/test_app/build/elinux/arm64/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:62 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/usr/bin/clang++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/tom/test_app/build/elinux/arm64/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_46f48/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_46f48.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_46f48.dir/build
    gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/tom/test_app/build/elinux/arm64/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_46f48.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    /usr/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --sysroot=/opt/arm64-sysroot    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_46f48.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -MF
    CMakeFiles/cmTC_46f48.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o.d -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_46f48.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c
    /home/tom/test_app/build/elinux/arm64/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    Linking CXX executable cmTC_46f48
    /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_46f48.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/bin/clang++ --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --sysroot=/opt/arm64-sysroot CMakeFiles/cmTC_46f48.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_46f48 
    /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find crtbeginS.o: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lm: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lgcc: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lc: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lgcc: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find crtendS.o: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_46f48.dir/build.make:100: cmTC_46f48] Error 1
    gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tom/test_app/build/elinux/arm64/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_46f48/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
```

For more specification, i am using the `flutter-elinux` [package](https://github.com/sony/flutter-elinux) to cross-compile and i have raised an issue there, but i am not sure the issue comes from the package as i don't know anything about linux compilation.

I have installed manually the following packages :

```
sudo apt install cpp-aarch64-linux-gnu
sudo apt install binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu
```

Thanks in advance for any help i really need to get this working...

EDIT : i have tried another solution using a docker container and the image `arm64v8/ubuntu:18.04`.
I have created a systroot `ubuntu18-arm64-sysroot` on my host and i use it to compile my app in `arm64` arch. I am having the following error only :

```
Failed to cmake:
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/tom/ubuntu18-arm64-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /home/tom/ubuntu18-arm64-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++ - broken
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/tom/test_app/build/elinux/arm64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/tom/test_app/build/elinux/arm64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:62 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "/home/tom/ubuntu18-arm64-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/tom/test_app/build/elinux/arm64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_848af/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f
    CMakeFiles/cmTC_848af.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_848af.dir/build
    gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/tom/test_app/build/elinux/arm64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_848af.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
    /home/tom/ubuntu18-arm64-sysroot/usr/bin/clang++    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_848af.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c
    /home/tom/test_app/build/elinux/arm64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
    aarch64-binfmt-P: Could not open '/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1': No such file or directory
    gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_848af.dir/build.make:78: CMakeFiles/cmTC_848af.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o] Error 255
    gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tom/test_app/build/elinux/arm64/debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_848af/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
```

Comment: Although the logs are helpful in understand the errors you are receiving, a small `CMakeList.txt` file AND the command you're using to invoke it would be helpful in understanding how the build is firing.  Do you mind updating your example with a small, reproducible CMake example?  For example, adding custom build flags can break a compiler that's not expecting them; knowledge of a custom CMake toolchain file would help add context as well, etc.

Comment: Alright thanks for your comment i will try to update the question and provide all the info you asked

Comment: `cpp` is just the preprocessor package. This doesn't accomplish anything useful. Looking through apt-cache, `g++-aarch64-linux-gnu` would be at least what I'd want installed if my plans were to compile C++ code.

Comment: Well thanks @SamVarshavchik i have an another error now after installing your package, i will update the question.

Comment: At a glance, you will need to add the `aarch64` version of any dependent libraries.  https://askubuntu.com/a/1323570/412004.

Comment: There's only a small number of cross-compiled `aarch64` packages that appear to be available on amd64 Ubuntu. Looks like the only stuff that's been cross-compiled are basic, core, C++ libraries, and pretty much nothing else. In order to build software that, for example, uses X it is necessary to have those cross-compiled libraries installed as well. There appear none on Ubuntu, so you cannot cross-compile this software package on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies guys. I have tried your link @tresf but it doesn't work either :(. So if i understand correctly, i can't cross compile on Ubuntu. If so, what kind of VM can i use to be able to cross-compile for `aarch64` ? I rephrase, what kind of Linux distribution should i use ?

Comment: I have tested another solution using docker with an arm64 image to build my sysroot but i have another kind of error...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik these libraries should be available once the architecture has been added.  Also, clarification, I wrote `aarch64`, but it appears Ubuntu specifically refers to these as `arm64`.  Can you clarify what you mean when you say "small number of packages"?  I run Ubuntu ARM64 as a standard operating system and most dev libraries are available, meaning they'll become available to x86_64 once the architecture has been added to `apt`.

Comment: @trest -- `apt-cache search aarch64` comes back with only 51 packages, most of them compiler packages. `apr-cache search arm64` comes back with more, about 150. On amd64 there are only a very small number of packages that have been cross-compiled for arm64/aarch64. I wasn't aware that `apt` can be configured to install packages directly from a different arch.

Comment: Alright guys i have managed to compile by using a ubuntu server arm64 VM with the 22.04 LTS release. Thanks again for your help on this but this is beyond my skills to cross compile with the amd64, the easiest way is to compile on the correct architecture whenever possible... I leave the question opened as my resolution doesn't answer this.